# COCOS-2d-x: Idea to implement Level progress in games

Tags: android, c++, ios, iphone, cocos2d-x

I have developed a android game with 18 levels. I have menu at starting screen which has 18 buttons for 18 levels.

For example If user dont finish level 1 level 2 button should not be enabled ,and so on.as user finish some levels in game the next level should be enabled.
I want to create levels as cpp file and not as a "plist" files

Answer (score 2):

Laying out level buttons

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
    auto levelButton = Button::create();
    levelButton->setEnabled(isLevelFinished(i));
    levelButton->setTitleText(String::createWithFormat("%d",i)->getCString());        
    // You may change button the texture according to level completion information

}

bool HelloWorld::isLevelFinished(int levelIndex)
{
    return UserDefault::getInstance()->getBoolForKey(String::createWithFormat("isLevelFinished_%d", levelIndex)->getCString(), false);
}
```

When a level is finished, call :

```
void HelloWorld::setLevelFinished(int levelIndex)
{
    UserDefault::getInstance()->setBoolForKey(String::createWithFormat("isLevelFinished_%d", levelIndex)->getCString(), true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CCUserDefault and save bool keys for every level. Keep buttons enabled or disabled for level buttons depending on CCUserDefault values.
Also you can create a Sqlite db if you want to store more complex data